# How to subtract a number from date parameter in Sql

Tags: sql, toad

I wana pick Rate from a table for previous day. What I am doing is to to subtract 1 form date parameter but after executing this query I am getting an error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER".Kindly guide me how to overcome this error. Thanks in advance.
My Sample query is:

```
SELECT   CCY_RATE.MID_REVAL_RATE
  FROM   curr_currency_market_his CCY_RATE
 WHERE       CCY_RATE.CURR_ID = a.CCY_BOUGHT
         AND CCY_RATE.CURRENCY_MARKET = 1
         AND CCY_RATE.LEAD_COMPANY = 1
         AND CCY_RATE.BANKING_DATE  =:Report_date -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query to get previous day:

```
SELECT   CCY_RATE.MID_REVAL_RATE
  FROM   curr_currency_market_his CCY_RATE
 WHERE       CCY_RATE.CURR_ID = a.CCY_BOUGHT
         AND CCY_RATE.CURRENCY_MARKET = 1
         AND CCY_RATE.LEAD_COMPANY = 1
         AND CCY_RATE.BANKING_DATE  =DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, :Report_date), -1);
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh G, I tried this but unfortunately DATEADD and DATEDIFF functions are not supported. I tried "CCY_RATE.BANKING_DATE  =to_date((:Report_date) - 1),'DD/MM/YYYY')" as a workaround as well but it didn't work. !

Comment: which sql version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it using --> to_date((to_date(:Report_date,'DD/MM/YYYY') - 1),'DD/MM/YY');

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_SUB to remove time

```
SELECT CCY_RATE.MID_REVAL_RATE
FROM   curr_currency_market_his CCY_RATE
WHERE  CCY_RATE.CURR_ID = a.CCY_BOUGHT
     AND CCY_RATE.CURRENCY_MARKET = 1
     AND CCY_RATE.LEAD_COMPANY = 1
     AND CCY_RATE.BANKING_DATE  = DATE_SUB(:Report_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Here you're saying that you want to remove '1 day' from your `:Report_date`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT CCY_RATE.mid_reval_rate 
FROM   curr_currency_market_his CCY_RATE 
WHERE  CCY_RATE.curr_id = a.ccy_bought 
    AND CCY_RATE.currency_market = 1 
    AND CCY_RATE.lead_company = 1 
    AND Cast(CCY_RATE.banking_date AS DATE) >= Cast(report_date - 1 AS DATE)
```

Comment: using cast it is again throwing same error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER"

Comment: Hi, M.Ali my answer is as per Sql Server, Your error is from Oracle Db, Please review your Column datatype and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get this done through mysql, try this,

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,  DATEADD(day, -1, @CreatedDate), GETDATE())
```

If not working, then you can calculate the date through php and pass the actual date. To calculate the date through php try this :

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime(report_date))));
```